# How to I spend energy to get the World Wonder and fix the bridge

Tags: android, paradise-island

In Game Insight's "Paradise Island" for android devices, what does it mean when we need to achieve 500

> energy spent
>   with something to do with mining and energy to be able to get the 3rd stage of the World Wonder.

And similarly, to fix the bridge we need to

> scour the river bed
>   for1000 something's, with the same symbols indicating mining and energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are [Energy Zaps](http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Energy_Zaps_and_Batteries#Energy_Zaps).

> Several features in the game require the use of Energy Zaps to accomplish given tasks. These tasks include some steps in building the Wonder of the World, uncovering the Idol, repairing or upgrading the Bridge, fixing or upgrading the Pharos, and many special events.

In terms of the Bridge quest, the following advice is given:

> Scout the riverbed. Provide it with 1,000 energy zaps Action energy drop. **(Open the quest window, click on hammer Button hammer active﻿. This will consume energy).**

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. I thought it might be something like the Independence points, but I couldn't work it out.